# calculate google maps GPS coordinates based on image size at a zoom level

Tags: google-maps, gps

I want to calculate the image dimensions in GPS coordinates scale based on a certain zoom level in google maps. Basically I want to find the distance between adjacent pixels in GPS coordinates scale.
How can I do this (what's the equation)?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a class dealing with Mercator projection and tile size conversion [here](http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/). You should be able to use a lot of these utility functions to compute this.